# Python read a configuration file from bitbucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, bitbucket

I have a python script which works with a JSON file as a configuration. Now, it is decided to put the JSON file in a bitbucket cloud account.
What is the best solution to read that JSON file in my script?

Comment: Is the JSON file in the cloud account publicly accessibly via URL, or do you need to authenticate to access it?

Comment: yes the JSON file is in the private repo in the bitbucket, also I can put it in the gitlab. so again I need to access to a bitbucket/gitlab private repos

Comment: You could use the python package `atlassian-python-api` which is a python wrapper for the BitBucket API. This would allow you to authenticate and access the private repo via Python. Then you could get the JSON file with `BitBucket.get_content_of_file`. More details: https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/

Comment: @clarked Many thanks. Do you know how can we read from a specific branch? I was trying the parameter "at" but seems there's not much reference.

Answer (score 1):

change org_name to your_org_name and run script by passing reponame it will clone and print all files in the repo

````
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import sys, os
import subprocess
import logging

# connect to bitbucket and get repo
repoName = sys.argv[1]
bitBucketUrl = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<org_name>/{}/src'.format(repoName)
userName = '*******'
password = '*******'
response = requests.get(bitBucketUrl, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(userName,password))
json_response = response.json()
#print(response)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("success")
else:
    print("Unable to retrive bitbucket repo details")

#remove directory if exists
check_for_repo = os.path.exists(repoName)
if (check_for_repo):
    remove_dir = 'rm -rf {}'.format(repoName)
    os.system(remove_dir)
    print("Removed the directory if already exists")
else:
    print("The directory is not present ! Skipping for now")

# clone repo from bitbucket 
clone_repo = ['git', 'clone', 'https://{}:{}@bitbucket.org/<org_name>/{}.git'.format(userName ,password ,repoName)]
res = subprocess.Popen(clone_repo, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, _error = res.communicate()
currentPath = os.getcwd()
destinationPath = os.chdir(currentPath + '/' + repoName)

#List files in directory
files_in_repo = os.listdir()
print(files_in_repo)```

noe that you have all the files you can just read them like you would read normal files
````